# ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I'm building an application with Flutter with the maps API, after adding the "location" plugin to pubspec, I receive the error message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

upgrade flutter using this command `flutter upgrade` .

mostly this upgrade is fixed your problem. if not your problem fixed check your gradle version and use current gradle version compatible kotlin version.